# Migration of existing data to PostgreSQL on ROR. Foreign Key needs rewriting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ms-access, foreign-key-relationship, database-migration

I have an MS Access database with many tables, which are interlinked with Foreign keys. I am planning to put in on the web in an RoR application ( with Postgres). My question is, how does active_record handle foreign keys when data is being restored from pg_dump? The dump is created by converting the MS Access database. It has Integer fields which were originally AutoNumber of MS Access. I've made the schema with has_many, belongs_to and HABTM  models and migrated. But will I have to rewrite the Foreign keys as the existing local keys will be replaced with new SEQUENCE numbers?

Comment: o_O? `pg_dump` restores sequence positions too. It'd be utterly useless for backup and restore if it didn't.

Comment: Sorry! I should've specified, . Modifying the question.